# Cannot connect to database,.Login failed for user

Tags: sql-server-2008, authentication, windows-server-2008, windows-server-2008-r2, ssms

Yesterday my database was connected perfectly.

We have installed Windows Server 2008 R2 on our server and the I have added the user to the client PC name SMTECH5 with user jangid

Now my database is not connecting using windows authentication.

only the master database is connecting.

Here's the the error:

> Cannot connect to SMTECH5\COLLEGEERP.
>
> Cannot open user default database. Login failed.
> Login failed for user 'SMTECH\jangid'. (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 4064)

Comment: which user logged in correctly on your machine? I'm pretty sure it wasn't jangid. Which is the default database for that user? It looks like you forgot to set the user rights on that database

Comment: the default database has been removed as the Windows Server has been changed to Window Server 2008 r2

Comment: that's the problem, you have to set the default database for the user to an existing user, see the answer

Comment: <offtopic>Now I have a certain Beatles song in my head</offtopic>

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you go to enterprise manager as a different user, go to the security, logins node and select the user - then change the default database to master.

That should sort it.

Comment: I am using Sql Server Management Studio 2008 R2 Express

Comment: It should still work - In sql server management studio can you see the security node?

Comment: '
Cannot show requested dialog.

ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:

Cannot show requested dialog. (SqlMgmt)

Failed to connect to server SMTECH5\COLLEGEERP. (Microsoft.SqlServer.ConnectionInfo)

Cannot open user default database. Login failed.
Login failed for user 'SMTECH\jangid'. (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 4064)

For help, click: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?ProdName=Microsoft+SQL+Server&EvtSrc=MSSQLServer&EvtID=4064&LinkId=20476
' @ross-dargan

Comment: Connect to the server and try logging in as a local admin. You must log in as a different user however.

Comment: I tried that but the same error from local user too i.e., login windows as Administrator

Comment: You can alter the default database by using the following command:- sqlcmd -d master -U sa -P mypassword

Comment: i dont know the password for sa and no other user can be created

Comment: You can drop the -u and -p and it will run for the current user: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162773.aspx

Comment: from the command prompt - you should be able to find the file on the server in the program files folder - it will be in the tools folder.

Comment: This works for me - must be run on the server "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\80\Tools\Binn>sqlcmd -d master"

Comment: can u look at this using team viewer

Comment: I can't I'm afraid - It you are getting a timeout whilst trying to login is sounds like your sql server box is screwed - resetting it could help.

Answer (score 3):

The reason is because the default database has been removed (look comment on the question).
You have to Open Sql Server Management Studio, connect to the database, then open Security -> Logins-> right click on the account jangid -> Properties: on the bottom of the window you have to change the default database to the available one, or master.

Comment: there is no login account named jangid only sa and BUILTIN/Users are there

Comment: And on the security tab of the database you are connecting to? It seems like the user is not properly configured on your db

Comment: Add a new login to the Security -> Logins -> right click using as Account name the one you are using

Comment: and leave the default database to master or change it to the existing one

Comment: do it with the sysadmin account

Comment: Logging in using SqlServer authentication and the "sa" account

Comment: then ask the database administrator to properly configure the user for you

Comment: i am the all and all for the pc and servere

Comment: oh, then you should log to the server with the user you used to install and configure it. Probably it is the local administrator of you server machine

Answer (score 2):

Try [this](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2008/11/04/sql-server-fix-error-4064-cannot-open-user-default-database-login-failed-login-failed-for-user/) in SQL Server Management Studio.

1: Open 'Connect to Server' popup

2: Select 'Options >>'

3: Change the value in the dropdown 'Connect to database' from `<default>` to `master`.

Comment: The question has been asked 2 years back. I found my answer, the second day I posted this question.